# Different ways of entry points in a form or one way?

Tags: forms, user-behavior

So I am trying to digitalise a business form for my client.
I will quickly explain the workflow:

1. User fills a form which has:

   - shipping address
   - payer address
   - billing address.

2.They create a new form for each shipping address they have.

3.He may add new shippings or make changes in old shippings form.

---

I planned to have a screen with the list of all the shippings he has filled earlier and make changes to it. My suggestion is that there should be one entry point to every form. User should search the form and edit it.

But my client wants a button saying "Maintain Shipping" after clicking on it they search the shippings and make changes to it.

Does that make sense? any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add some sketches of what you have in mind because this is quite confusing

Comment: can't understand clearly what does the maintain shipping button

Answer (score 0):

So you are talking about a monthly shipping where the users must confirm that they still want the order by clicking the maintain shipping or edit the form if they want to modify it somehow. This is not a very standard solution. I would recommend at least notifying the users a day before that they need to confirm or edit the shipment and then send a confirmation email that it was successful.